# Estimating the Percent of Donut Lovers in the Population

Tags: probability

- Suppose 2020, there are 100 people: 75 in Group A and 25 in Group B.
- 83% of people in Group A like donuts, but we don't know what percent of people in Group B like donuts. However, we think that it is unlikely that more than 83% of people in Group B like donuts.
- In 2021, there is a brand new population (i.e. no one from 2020) of 150 people (that we believe might have similar donut preferences as the 2020 population). However, we don't know what percent of the 2021 population will be in Group A and what percent will be in Group B.
- Problem: **Can we estimate the total percent of people in 2021 that might like donuts?**
- To make the problem simpler, I am assuming independence between population ratios and donut preferences

From a pure Frequentist approach, I think this problem is impossible since we have too little information to work with. However, I think using a Bayesian approach, we might be able to come up with some limited answer to this problem. I attempted to work on this problem and will display my progress in parts.

**Part 1: Identify all symbols that will be used throughout the question:**

- $D_{A,2020}$: Number of people in group A who like donuts in 2020.
- $N_{A,2020}$: Total number of people in group A in 2020.
- $D_{B,2020}$: Number of people in group B who like donuts in 2020.
- $N_{B,2020}$: Total number of people in group B in 2020.
- $p_{A,2020}$: Probability of a person in group A liking donuts in 2020.
- $p_{B,2020}$: Probability of a person in group B liking donuts in 2020.

**Part 2: Identify all Probability Distributions that might be useful in this problem**

- **Binomial Distribution**: The probability of getting $k$ successes (donut likers) in $n$ trials (total people) and $p$ is the probability of success on an individual trial.:

$$
P(k; n, p) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$

- **Beta Distribution**: The Beta Distribution is defined over the interval [0, 1] parameterized by two positive shape parameters, denoted by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (and $B(\alpha, \beta)$ is the Beta function):

$$
P(p; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{p^{\alpha-1} (1-p)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$

- **Dirichlet Distribution**: Parameterized by a vector $\alpha$ of positive real numbers. Apparently, it is a multivariate generalization of the Beta distribution (again, $B(\alpha)$ is the multivariate Beta function):

$$
P(x_1, ..., x_K; \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_K) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha)} \prod_{i=1}^{K} x_i^{\alpha_i - 1}
$$

- **Multinomial Distribution:**

$$P(X) = \frac{n!}{X_1!X_2!...X_k!}p_1^{X_1}p_2^{X_2}...p_k^{X_k}$$

**Part 3: Analysis for People in 2020**

- **Likelihood for Group A Donut Lovers**: This can be modeled using the binomial distribution:

$$
P(D_{A,2020} | p_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) = \binom{N_{A,2020}}{D_{A,2020}} p_{A,2020}^{D_{A,2020}} (1-p_{A,2020})^{N_{A,2020}-D_{A,2020}}
$$

- **Likelihood for Group B Donut Lovers**: (Problem) There is no Likelihood for Group B Donut Lovers (by definition) - we can only assume some value of value of $pB,2020$ , ideally less than than $pA,2020$ with a "wider" Prior. Is this a problem?
- **Prior for Group A Donut Lovers ($p_{A,2020}$)**: We can model this using a Beta distribution. The parameters of this Beta distribution would depend on our prior knowledge or beliefs about $p_{A,2020}$.

$$ P(p_{A,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020}) = \frac{p_{A,2020}^{\alpha_{A,2020}-1} (1-p_{A,2020})^{\beta_{A,2020}-1}}{B(\alpha_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020})}$$

- **Prior for Group B Donut Lovers ($p_{B,2020}$)**: I think a Beta prior distribution can still be used here, but I am not sure how to make it so that $p_{B,2020}$ can not be more than 0.83. I think perhaps the concept of truncated distribution might be useful here, or numerically integrate a Beta Distribution where the bulk of the mass occurs before 0.83? I also think the "overall spread" of this Beta Prior (i.e. Group B) should be "wider" than the overall spread of the first Beta Prior (i.e. Group A), given that there is more uncertainty in the Group B compared to Group A?

$$\int_{0.83}^{1} Beta(p; α, β) dp < 0.01$$

$$ P(p_{B,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{B,2020}, \beta_{B,2020}) = \frac{p_{B,2020}^{\alpha_{B,2020}-1} (1-p_{B,2020})^{\beta_{B,2020}-1}}{B(\alpha_{B, 2020}, \beta_{B,2020})}$$

- **Likelihood for the Ratio Counts:** Denote the observed counts of people in groups A and B as $N_{A,2020}$ and $N_{B,2020}$, . The likelihood of these counts given the proportions $x_{A,2020}$ and $x_{B,2020}$ can be modeled using a multinomial distribution:

$$
P(N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020} | x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) \propto x_{A,2020}^{N_{A,2020}} x_{B,2020}^{N_{B,2020}}
$$

- **Prior for the Ratio**: Given the ratio of people in group A to B is around 3:1, we can model the sizes of groups A and B using a Dirichlet distribution with $\alpha = 3$ and $\beta = 1$:

If $x_{A,2020}$ and $x_{B,2020}$ are the proportions of people in groups A and B:

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) = \frac{1}{B(3, 1)} x_{A,2020}^{3-1} x_{B,2020}^{1-1}
$$

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) = \frac{1}{B(3, 1)} x_{A,2020}^{2} x_{B,2020}^{0}
$$

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) = \frac{1}{B(3, 1)} x_{A,2020}^{2}
$$

**Part 3: Writing the Posterior Distributions**

The Posterior Distributions for donut lovers in Group A and Group B will both have Beta Distributions. This is because of the Beta-Binomial Conjugacy (note  $D_{B,2020}$ is unknown and I am not sure how to deal with this, i.e. truncation):

$$
P(p_{A,2020} | D_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) \propto P(D_{A,2020} | p_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) \cdot P(p_{A,2020})
$$

$$
P(p_{A,2020} | D_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) \propto \binom{N_{A,2020}}{D_{A,2020}} p_{A,2020}^{D_{A,2020}} (1-p_{A,2020})^{N_{A,2020}-D_{A,2020}} \cdot \frac{p_{A,2020}^{\alpha_{A,2020}-1} (1-p_{A,2020})^{\beta_{A,2020}-1}}{B(\alpha_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020})}
$$

$$
P(p_{A,2020} | D_{A,2020}, N_{A,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{A,2020} + D_{A,2020}, \beta_{A,2020} + N_{A,2020} - D_{A,2020})
$$

$$
P(p_{B,2020} | D_{B,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \sim Beta(\alpha_{B,2020} + D_{B,2020}, \beta_{B,2020} + N_{B,2020} - D_{B,2020})
$$

The posterior for the ratio uses the Multinomial-Dirichlet Conjugacy - thus, the posterior of the ratio will be a Dirichlet:

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020} | N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \propto P(N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020} | x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020}) \cdot P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020})
$$

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020} | N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \propto x_{A,2020}^{N_{A,2020}} x_{B,2020}^{N_{B,2020}} \cdot x_{A,2020}^{2}
$$

$$
P(x_{A,2020}, x_{B,2020} | N_{A,2020}, N_{B,2020}) \sim Dirichlet(N_{A,2020} + 2, N_{B,2020})
$$

**Part 4: MAP Estimators of the Posteriors**

Now, we can find out the MAP estimators for these Posteriors - as an example;:

$$\hat{x}_{MAP} = \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha + \beta - 2}$$

**Conclusion:** Thus, if you know the total number of people in 2021 - via the Posterior MAP's,we can estimate the expected ratio of people in A:B ... and then estimate the percent of A that will like donuts and estimate the percent of B that will like donuts.

- Is my analysis correct?
- And can some prior be selected for $p_{B,2020}$ such that it respects the 0.83 constraint?

**Note: Further justification for parameter choices for the Dirichlet Prior.**

If a random variable $X$ has a Dirichlet Distribution, then the Expected value of X is given by:

$$
E[x_i] = \frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{K} \alpha_j}
$$

Thus, using a Dirichlet Distribution with a Beta(3,1) will result in the desired population ratios:

$$
E[x_A] = \frac{\alpha_A}{\alpha_A + \alpha_B} = \frac{3}{3 + 1} = 0.75
$$

$$
E[x_B] = \frac{\alpha_B}{\alpha_A + \alpha_B} = \frac{1}{3 + 1} = 0.25
$$

So, on average, we expect 75% of the population to be in group A and 25% to be in group B, which is a 3:1 ratio.